# Automatically name the elements of a list after importing using lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of dataframes which I imported using

```
setwd("C:path")
fnames <- list.files()
csv <- lapply(fnames, read.csv, header = T, sep=";")
```

I will need to do this multiple times creating more lists, I would like to keep all the dataframes available separately (i.e. I don't want or need to combine them), I simply used the above code to import them all in quickly. But accessing them now is a little cumbersome and not intuitive (to me at least). Rather having to use `[[1]]` to access the first element, is there a way that I could amend the first bit of code so that I can name the elements in the list, for example based off a `Date` which is a variable in each of the dataframes in the list? The dates are stored as `chr` in the format `"dd-mm-yyyy"` , so I could potentially just name the dataframes using `dd-mm` from the `Date` variable.

Comment: Does one file contain only one date?

Comment: one option is  to use `sapply` instead of `lapply` which will use the file names as list names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the required data from the 1st value in the `Date` column of each dataframe and assign it as name of the list.

```
names(csv) <- sapply(csv, function(x) substr(x$Date[1], 1, 5))
```

Or extract the data using regex.

```
names(csv) <- sapply(csv, function(x) sub("(\\w+-\\w+).*", "\\1", x$Date[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
names(csv) <- sapply(csv, function(x) substring(x$Date[1], 1, 5))
```